# Node.js - Is it possible to use two template languages?

Tags: node.js

I have build my node project using ejs view engine. I want to add blog module to my website. I choose [poet](http://jsantell.github.com/poet/) which is using jade template language.

Is it possible to directly use those jade files along with my ejs files or do i need to manually convert jade to ejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can. Just use the appropriate template engine to process the file in question (probably determined either by file extension or a location-based rule such as "all entries in /blog are Jade").

Comment: I couldn't find any example for location-based rule but it worked when referring the views with extension (jade)